# I'm trying to encorporate php into js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

so I have this jquery script that lets the user press arrows to choose different episodes, like [this](https://gyazo.com/6ed833bc7b5f782a72d1034e77264474)
it works and all but I have an admin panel that sends variables with sessions, I want the admin to be able to modify the links that the buttons direct, for ex: I want the admin to be able to modify the 6th button, but since the button isn't always present i dont know how to do it, I tried this in js:

```
sixth = '<li class="liclass1" style="margin-left: 10px;">"<?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['six'])) {
                $a6 = $_SESSION['six'];
                echo '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$a6.'"  id="6">6</a>';
                } else {
                    echo '<a href=""  id="6">6</a>';
                    } ?>"</li>';
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server! Javascript runs on the browser! Your code cannot work

Comment: is there any way I can maybe check if it exists and change the `<a>`'s `href`?

Comment: You need to look up AJAX and do some reading around the subject

Comment: @guy, yes. You can use `AJAX`. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks, Researching right now! :D

Comment: Do you guys have some good guides on Ajax? or some good resources you can recommend me?

Comment: @guy It's called [Google](http://google.com), and that question is very much off-topic.